# How to code a function to be used with or without callback on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm wondering how (if possible) I can create the same function, with exactly the same functionality, but to be used with a callback or without it. Here is an example with the "wanted effect" that is not working:

```
function getUsers(req, res, onComplete) {
    // If the user is not logged in send an error. In other case, send data
    if (!req.session.session_id) {
        if (typeof onComplete === 'function') {
            onComplete({error: true, msg: 'You are not logged in'});
        } else {
            res.json({error: true, msg: 'You are not logged in'});
        }  
    } else {
        //Another similar code...
    }
}
```

It's not working because if I call "getUsers(req, res)", the typeof onComplete is always function, so I cannot detect when I call with or without the callback.

The exact problem is that I can call this function from inside my code, with callback (a normal call, like `getUsers(req, res, function(cb) {//Do something with cb});` OR I can call this function from an AJAX call in my website, like `http://localhost:8080/api/getUsers`, what in that case is when it don't works.

In the last case I get `typeof onComplete === 'function'` as true, so I never get the else part executed. I'm supposing that the "request" done by the http call have more parameters than req&res, and that's the reason why onComplete is a function, instead of undefined.

The usual AJAX call is like this (javascript in the client side):

```
function getAllUsers() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/getUsers',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            // Remove item and set as main topic the assigned on the server 
            printUsers(data.users[0]);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText); 
        } 
    });
}
```

And the route defined in the config.json of my Node.JS to call the final function is like that:

```
{"path": "/api/getUsers", "method":"get", "callback": "api#getUsers"},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call getUsers without onComplete the value will be set to undefined. You can then check that case in your function.

```
function getUsers(req, res, onComplete) {
    // Set onComplete to default call back if it is undefined
    onComplete = onComplete || function(msg){ res.json(msg) };

    if (!req.session.session_id) {
        onComplete({error: true, msg: 'You are not logged in'});  
    } else {
        //Another similar code...
    }
}
```

See http://www.markhansen.co.nz/javascript-optional-parameters/ for more ways of doing this

Comment: Well, it seems that I'm stupid, because I tested my code again and now it works. Don't know why the first time it didn't work, maybe I wrote something different this time. Your solution is elegant... if I only return the same value everytime, and if I expect a callback always, but my case was that return could be a res.json if the initial call is without callback (so I will not expect any return), or a callback if I call with it (I will be waiting for the return).

Comment: Ok, not working, now I've do some alternative tests and it's not working "as I need". More info in the main title